# PyTest fixture not found while using with another fixture

Tags: python-2.7, pytest, fixtures

I am new to python. I have declared one fixture `configure_loggers()` with scope as 'session'. Now, I want to use this fixture before another fixture `setup_app()`, which is also scoped as 'session'.

Fixture 1:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def configure_loggers(request):
    LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Fixture 2:

```
from fixtures.logger_config import configure_loggers

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def frapp(configure_loggers, request, context):
    start_appium()
     # do some other stuff
```

I have tried to add logging fixture to parameters as well as `@pytest.mark.usefixtures('configure_loggers')`. However I am getting following error:

```
fixture 'configure_loggers' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, caplog, capsys, capturelog, context, doctest_namespace, enable_voice, frapp, launch_app, login, metadata, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_xml_property, recwarn, skip_tests_for_ios, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

I have tried to put the fixtures in same file as well. But, still getting same error.

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: Remove fixture import, move fixtures code to test module or `conftest.py`.

Comment: @hoefling - Your solution worked for me. I tweaked it a bit. Added the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by doing this import in `conftest.py`.

```
from fixtures.logger_config import configure_loggers
```

- Note: Fixture is still in separate file.

Comment: I guess you meant `conftest.py`